# Western Digital External Hard Drive Isn't Compatible with Newer Windows Systems?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My old 10TB WD Elements external hard drive works with multiple old laptops without any issue for years and is currently still working.

The external hard drive comes with an external power supply.

But when plugged into a newer laptop - which works with a variety of other USB devices including a 1TB WD Elements portable - what I see is that although the 10 TB WD drive shows up on File Explorer and has a letter assigned to it, but I am unable to open, and file explorer continues to hang. Please note the progress on top of the file explorer bar - it has been over a few minutes like this.
[image: Unable to load]

Furthermore, I am also not able to open Disk Management (it hangs on "Connecting to Virtual Disk Service..").

[image: Connecting to Virtual Disk Service]

I think my issue is very similar to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/431991/my-wd-passport-detected-but-not-working/487310#487310), but I have a letter assigned, and I am not able to open up Disk Management (hence I'm creating a new post here).

I reached out to WD support and all they can suggest is that I reformat the disk as NTFS (which it already is), and after reformatting, the same issue still persists.

The fact that it works on old laptops but not newer ones (also not on my newer **desktop**) makes me can't help but think the WD Elements drive aren't compatible with newer hardware.

**EDIT**: I turned on my newer **desktop** and gave the thing another try and voila, one of my external hard drive is successfully connected.

Try the other external hard drive, it does not show up on File Explorer. Switch to another USB port, it gets stuck in a reset loop. Try another USB port, it powers up like a charm.

Now I wonder if this is some type of USB connector issue... But in any case, I'd need to figure out what's going on here, as the newer laptop does not have that many USB ports to try on, and none of them worked so far.

Any help is appreciated!

**TL;DR** Version: WD Elements isn't being recognized on my new laptop but works on old laptop; connecting to a newer desktop experienced many issues ranging from unable to be recognized to reset cycles but changing USB ports eventually solved the issue on desktop. What the hell is going on here and why isn't it working with my new laptop?

Comment: See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/ls033d/just_shucked_a_10tb_wd_elements_having_issues/?rdt=34147) on reddit.  I was assuming the same as what they are saying on that post.

Comment: what exact model? does it allow for an external power connector?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen It is this model (https://www.westerndigital.com/products/external-drives/wd-elements-desktop-usb-3-0-hdd?sku=WDBWLG0040HBK-NESN), and yes it comes with an external power connector.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas This reminds me during the old days when I did exactly this when my external hard drive refuses to turn on. Here, the drive turns on but isn't being correctly recognized by the system, it seems.

Comment: What size (dimentions) is this HD?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ‎5.31 x 1.89 x 6.53 inches